# Map and orElse returning different subtypes

Tags: java, lambda, compiler-errors

I have two functions - one returning `Set<String>` and another returning `List<String>`.

```
private static List<String> getStringList(final String factor) {
    ....
}

private static Set<String> getStringSet() {
    ....
}
```

Now, I have a function to return a `Collection<String>` which in turn calls the above functions based on a certain condition. I want to do something like this:

```
private static Collection<String> getStringCollection() {
    Optional<String> factor = getFactor();
    return factor.filter(LambdaTest::someCondition)
            .map(LambdaTest::getStringList)
            .orElse(getStringSet());
}
```

But I get this error

> Error:(24, 37) java: incompatible types: java.util.Set cannot be converted to java.util.List

I can understand what's going on here. But is there a way to achieve something similar without doing an elaborate if-else statement like this?

```
private static Collection<String> getStringCollection() {
    Optional<String> factor = getFactor();

    if(factor.isPresent() && someCondition(factor.get())) {
        return getStringList(factor.get());
    }

    return getStringSet();
}
```

Comment: what's the harm in changing to `Collection<String> getStringList(final String factor)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a generic type specification to force `getStringList` to be treated as a `Collection<String>`:

```
return factor.filter(LambdaTest::someCondition)
             .<Collection<String>> map(LambdaTest::getStringList)
             .orElse(getStringSet());
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this was obvious and stated in the latter part of the question, but what you could also do is change the signature of the `getStringList` method to return a `Collection<String>`, keeping its implementation still same as earlier.

So that the complete implementation would look like :

```
Collection<String> getStringList(final String factor) { ... }

Set<String> getStringSet() { ... }

private Collection<String> getStringCollection() {
    Optional<String> factor = getFactor();
    return factor.filter(this::someCondition)
            .map(this::getStringList)
            .orElseGet(this::getStringSet);
}
```

Another alternative is to initialise the `Set` in `orElse` to return a `List` using `new ArrayList<>`:

```
private Collection<String> getStringCollection() {
    Optional<String> factor = getFactor();
    return factor.filter(this::someCondition)
            .map(this::getStringList)
            .orElse(new ArrayList<>(getStringSet()));
}
```